# Using FBSession.FBSessionState values within swift

Tags: ios, facebook, session, swift, sdk

I'm using FacebookSDK.framework to build an **iOS** app (in **Swift**). In order to check for a cached session when entering the app, Facebook Developers Documentation suggests to check the following:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) { ...
```

which in Swift I supposed is:

```
if FBSession.activeSession().state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded { ...
```

xCode (ver. 6.1) gets a compile error on `FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded:`

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded'".

Note that I tried the followings (reported with the relative compiling error):

- `FBSessionState.FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded`

  > "'FBSessionState.Type' does not have a member named 'FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded'"
- `FBSession.FBSessionState.FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded`

  > "'FBSession.Type' does not have a member named 'FBSessionState'"
- `.FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded`

  > "'FBSessionState.Type' does not have a member named 'FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded'"

Any clue on how I can access `NS_ENUM` values stored inside a class using Swift? Thanks anyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out 2 minutes ago. Try:

```
if FBSession.activeSession().state == FBSessionState.CreatedTokenLoaded {
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: not working in xcode 6.3.1 beta  says: CreatedTokenLoaded not a member of FBSessionState,  Any idea??